# ASP .NET Core MapSpaFallbackRoute не работает

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, spa

Я пытаюсь сделать SPA приложение используя React как фронтенд и C# как бекенд. В реакте у меня используются такие маршруты как `/register` и `/register/conf`. Чтобы они работали на сервере на ASP, я использую `MapSpaFallbackRoute()`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", 
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

Но этот пример у меня не работает. Когда я пытаюсь, например, обновить или ввести в адресную строку непосредственно `/register`, то сервер возвращает мне 404 ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: хм, а у вас в принципе контроллер HomeController присутствует?

Comment: @PavelMayorov все, разобрался, это был мой тупой косяк с HomeController'ом, не так написан был. Ваше предыдущее сообщение помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас настроено два "универсальных" маршрута, т.е. маршрута которые могут обработать почти любой запрос. Неудивительно что один из них не работает! В частности, ваш маршрут `/register` определяется как *name: default, controller: register, action: Index*.

Вам нужно изменить первый их них так, чтобы он не срабатывал для пути `/register`. Это можно сделать несколькими способами.

Самый простой способ - перенести все контроллеры бекенда на другой виртуальный путь:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{action}");
```

Способ сложнее - регистрировать отдельный маршрут для каждого контроллера

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "foo", template: "Foo/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Foo" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "bar", template: "Bar/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Bar" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "baz", template: "Baz/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "Baz" });
```

Третий способ - то же самое, что и второй, но используя [маршруты основанные на атрибутах](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing)

```
[Route("Foo")]
public class FooController: Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня React + Asp.net core 2.1, настройка выглядит так

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

полет норм